# Basic JS/jQuery loop issue

Tags: jquery, while-loop

How would I incorporate `$('#featured article').last().empty();` into a basic JS/jQuery loop so that the loop continues until the number of instances of `#featured article` has reduced to a finite number of instances, four for example?

I'm thinking `do while` would be the most appropriate, however as the number of instances is reducing rather than increasing I don't appear to be able to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#featured_article` is an ID, and the DOM only allows one element for each ID. Change it to a class (i.e. `$('.featured_article')`) and jQuery will loop it for you. You can use .remove() instead of .empty() to actually remove the element from the DOM tree, which is, I think, what you are looking to do:

```
$('.featured_article').last().remove();
```

As far as a `while` loop, try this:

```
while ($('.featured_article').size() > 4)
{
  $('.featured_article').last().remove();
}
```

Comment: Of course. I was forgetting all about the `.each();` method. I'll accept as soon as the timer runs down. Thanks.

Comment: Edited. This should do exactly what you want.